# Does sankhara disappear in Samantha meditation or insight meditation?

Tags: theravada

If the doer disappears, all the  external objects disappear, what remains is the knower. Knower is known and knows.  Knower is consciousness,inner aspect.

Knower,outer aspect,objects.

Sankhara appears for Knower

If sankhara disappears pure consciousness will arise.

Which kind of a meditation  sankhara disappears?

Answer (score 1):

One moment Shankaras are noticed is during vipassana meditation through a detailed body-observation as you go across the areas where feelings are more rude or notorious.

In order to make disappear the shankara, the acceptance of the feelings which arise during a concrete body area observation is needed. Understand the feelings, then accept them.

This acceptance, releases  the shankara from the whole metaphysic body of the meditator, not just the physical one, releasing the emotional concept underlaying the apparition of the shankara.

Technically upon shankara dissapears, there will not be possible that the same concept generates a new shankara as it is learnt as inner experience. This allows the character to completely release misery and thus obtain a true [paññā](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Praj%C3%B1%C4%81_(Buddhism)) in the path of illumination.

Answer (score 1):

I think studying 9 levels of meditation (4 forms and 4 formless plus cessation)  might lead to an answer.

For first four form meditations, what disappear are 5 hindrances but you still have all 5 skandhas. Then from 4th jhana to Infinite space, form disappears.   Since I haven't gotten no where near that,  i assume is like existing without body. So from here on you have only 4 skandhas. Feelings, perceptions,  SANGKHARA (from your question,  sangkhara is still there) and conciousness.  When you are reached neither perception or perception level,  you still have 4 sakhandas left.   Then from when Buddha explained how ven. Sariputta enter cessation level,  he used sati or mindfulness as a tool.   Cessation level in pali is sanna-vedayid-nirode or extinguish of perception and feelings.   What left? Vinnana and sankhara.

5 hinderances disappear in first four mediations

Form disappear in 4 of formless perceptions.

Perception and feelings disappear in cessation mediation (as direct translation of Pali word sanna-vedayid-niroda)

So I'm not sure if it is possible to temporary suppress sankhara and conciousness while still alive.

I'm putting my answer up so I could be corrected if someone remember Pali texts somewhere that it is possible to suppress sankhara or conciousness.

Foot note correction:  I did some quick research for "cessation of perception and feeling" and found something in [Kāmabhū-sutta](https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/SN/SN41_6.html), in deed, all 5 skandhas are temporary extinguished during cessation meditation.

PS.  i dont have enough creadit to post comment so i am going to place my comment for you here. you dont need teachers.  Studying suttas and many of questions will be answered.  Be concerned if someone claims you have/have not accomplished such as such state.  From Migasala Sutta, only Buddha could tell someone's accomplishments.  Even Ven. Sariputta or Moggallana didnt make such proclaimation in others.
Let me put it this way, in one of sutta, first Jhanna, sounds are no longer a bother.  If i remember words correctly, sound is longer a thorn  for those in first jhanna.  Same for 5 sensual pleasures (sex craving is included), they disappear in first Jhanna.

I am not quoting Sam Harris as an authority figure of meditation, but this is exactly how i feel about my meditaion, especially part where he said "interrupt continuous personal dialog"

[Sam Harris: Mindfulness is Powerful](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iwac6Uk-zyk)

Comment: I don't know where I am in my meditation practice .I am doing  satarsathipattanaya, when walking meditation I lost perceptions of hearing,sitting meditation practice sometimes restless,sexual craving disappears can see the thoughts process of anger and automatically stop by another thought. Where I am ?I don't have a teacher  now.